# Swift unwind modal

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app where I have an error page displayed incase there is a network problem. The app has several storyboards, and this can happen anywhere.

```
 func displayErrorPage(errorCode: ErrorCode) -> Void {
    if !isDisplayingError {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isDisplayingError = true
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "alert", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlertScreen") as! AlertVC
            controller.errorCode = errorCode
            UIApplication.shared.topViewController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use unwind to dismiss it, to clear out any views and get back to the home page. I have used this in the alert view to close, but sometimes doesn't work.

```
 @IBAction func closeBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    flowError = true
    NetworkManager.shared().isDisplayingError = false
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToSH", sender: self)
 }
```

Anyone with some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create  the unwind segue IBAction**  in the view controller you want to unwind to.  Perhaps in your case it is `HomeViewController`. Add this code inside your `HomeViewController`

   ```
   @IBAction func unwindToHomeVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
   ```
2. **Wire up the unwind segue** - Control drag from `AlertVC’s` ViewController icon to exit icon in the `storyboard` choose the unwind segue action (`unwindToHomeVC`) that was created in step 1 from the list of IBActions.
3. **Specify a segue Identifier** - specify its identifier in the Attributes Inspector of the Utilities Pane. Ex: “`unwindToHomeVC`”
4. **Trigger unwind segue programmatically** - trigger that in the appropriate place. In your case close button action

   ```
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMenu", sender: self)
   ```

   It will work even if you work with multiple storyboard as well, if your setup is right. I hope that this one would help you.
   Thanks

Comment: thanks, but all that was done already. The problem was actually that sometimes there was no navigation controller present as I was using MKProgressHud during network calls.

Comment: Well. Then it depends on how you use are using  MKProgressHud. Could you explain it a bit more clear about that one?.